# Jupyterhub with nginx reverse proxy in a subpath

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, jupyterhub

I have a Ubuntu server running nginx on port `443` to serve some static content and Jupyterhub 0.8 on port `8000` for Python notebooks (jupyterhub is installed via pip and run as a service (not with Docker).

I would like to use nginx's reverse proxy to make jupyterhub accessible as a subpath, e.g. `example.com/jupyterhub`.

Following the documentation and some other discussions (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419414/jupyterhub-nginx-reverse-proxy)) here, I came up with the following nginx configuration:

```
server_tokens off;

server {
  listen      80;
  server_name example.com;
  rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl default_server;
  #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

  root /var/www/html;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

  # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
  server_name localhost;

  # certs sent to the client in SERVER HELLO are concatenated in 
  ssl_certificate
  ssl_session_timeout 1d;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
  ssl_session_tickets off;


  # modern configuration. tweak to your needs.
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256';
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (15768000 seconds = 6 months)
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

  # OCSP Stapling ---
  # fetch OCSP records from URL in ssl_certificate and cache them
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;

  location /jupyterhub/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000  
  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
  }
}
```

Plus, I set the following in `jupyterhub_conf.py`

```
c.JupyterHub.base_url = u'/jupyterhub'
c.JupyterHub.ip = '127.0.0.1'
```

When I visit `https://example.com/jupyterhub` I get a 502 error. Looking at the nginx `error.log` I find

```
*13 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: localhost, request: "GET /jupyterhub/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/jupyterhub/", host: "example.com"
```

A local `curl` of jupyterhub gives

```
$ curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8000/jupyterhub/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
> GET /jupyterhub/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Comment: Are you able to curl to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/jupyterhub/`?

Comment: @TarunLalwani no, I get `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

Comment: Are you using docker to run jupyterhub?

Comment: @TarunLalwani, no, it is installed via `pip` and run as a service.

Comment: What about `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8000/` ?

Comment: @TarunLalwani see the edited answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156668/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-pincopallino).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed your issue is that your Jupyter is running on https and you are using http for your `proxy_pass`. You need to change your nginx config to below

```
  location /jupyterhub/ {
    proxy_pass https://localhost:8000;
    ...
```

Also make sure there is no trailing slash in `https://localhost:8000`, so that `/jupyterhub/` is sent as a part of the url to `proxy_pass`.